# jquery script dosen't works in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I got problem with jquery code.It somehow doesn't work in safari browser. Rest of the browsers working fine but in safari I dont know why not any solution?

Index.php  - I have this code inside HEAD

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {

          var prilohy = <? php echo json_encode($linkpar); ?> ;

          if (prilohy == "Pizza") {
              $('#content_donaska_extra').show();
          } else if (prilohy == null) {
              $('#content_donaska_extra').show();
          } else {
              $('#content_donaska_extra').hide();
          }

      });
</script>
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: And `var prilohy = <? php echo json_encode($linkpar); ?> ;` looks like what in the source code...

Comment: nothing. #content_donaska_extra  should hide if the parameter NAME in url is not PIZZA or NULL.

Comment: Please add to the question what the browser is receiving (view page source), not what is in the source file. That tiny bit of PHP is probably hiding the actual problem you are having.

Comment: **And how was this *"[solved]"***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space between `<?` and `php`

```
var prilohy = <?php echo json_encode($linkpar); ?> ;
```

script be

```
$(document).ready(function () {

          var prilohy = <?php echo json_encode($linkpar); ?> ;

          if (prilohy == "Pizza" || prilohy == null) {
              $('#content_donaska_extra').show();
          } else {
              $('#content_donaska_extra').hide();
          }

      });
```

Comment: I need it because I have `$linkpar = $_GET['name'];`

Comment: But does space mean it will work with other browsers?

Comment: nothing and I dont have idea why everywhere is working except Safari